# Classification vs Regression: Which to choose?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification

Suppose I have some training data pairs $(x, y)$, where both $x$ and $y$ are real values between 0 and 1. I want to train a multi-layer neural network to predict the value of $y$ given a new $x$. Now, there are two ways to do this. One is to train the network for regression, mapping $x$ to a real-value for $y$ at the output node. The other is to discretise the data in $y$, and train the network for classification, mapping $x$ to several real-values for $y$ at output nodes.

My question is: Aside from the fact that classification will introduce discretisation errors, would there likely be difference in performance between the two methods? How can I determine which method would be the best for my particular data?

Thanks you!

Comment: Classification is just regression over a finite support.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, the only solution is to use regression as you need to predict the value of y rather than the class it will fall into. Discretising is rarely a solution, unless you are certain it will bring out some important information.

I believe you are misunderstanding the two concepts and the ways they should be used.

The fundamental difference between regression and classification problems is the following: The regression wants to learn a continuous target variable while the classification wants to learn a discrete such. This essentially splits the problem in two, as you have pointed out. If you are willing to predict what is the value of your predicted y, then this is a regression problem. In contrast, if you are willing to predict which class y falls into, then you should use classification.

Also note that neural networks are not always the most suitable way to go.

In summary, it is not the type of the problem that implies the efficiency, its the way you will approach it, once you have established it as a classification or regression one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I ask is that some of my training data has two rather different $y$ values for the same $x$ value. Therefore, training for regression might be tricky, because I am telling the network two different target values for the same input. I was thinking that if I discretised $y$, then I could train it for classification, and then for these examples, I would have two labels for the same $x$ value.....and this might be easier to solve than with regression...

Comment: I think it shouldn't matter as you will be assigning random initial weight values to your inputs anyway (given you use a NN). Thus, ensuring that those will not have direct effect on the output. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027598/why-should-weights-of-neural-networks-be-initialized-to-random-numbers) for more information on how the randomised initialisation works. Hope that helps.

Comment: For the data where the same $x$ has two different $y$ values, I suppose it might depend on the distance between these two $y$ values. If the distance is very small, then maybe regression would be the best solution, because the error in the loss function would be similar, and so they will "reinforce" each other. But if the distance between those $y$ values is very large, then the errors will be very different, and so they will "counter" each other. In that case, classification would be the best solution. Does that make sense...?

Comment: No because you will always get some irregularities in the data which might seem strange. There will be extreme values, bad features, inappropriate distributions etc. Instead, it might be useful plotting your data and observing the distribution, this will give you a notion about how is your data distributed - essentially you want to have a distribution that explains the data better - i.e. normal distribution. It might be useful working with the log form of your input data. It is really dependent on the data.

Answer (score 1):

Discretization will result in loss of information. There is no reason to do it, unless you are certain there will emerge some kind of strong overfitting in the continuous setting, stronger than the bias you create with discretization (lol).

Answer (score -1):

I understand that your data points are both real. Assuming dataset does not have temporal dimension regression model is more suitable than classification. If  you use classification you -probably- will have to calculate continues values for *y*.

In summary:

- **Use regression** if you need exact values of *y* for all corresponding *x* values.
- **Use classification** if you need just general inferences for *y* values.

For example:
Let *x* be the daylight duration and *y* be the average temperature.

- **regression** for predicting temperature in degrees.
- **classification** for predicting temperature as as *low*, *medium* or *high*.